# How to make $resource.post call without sending data

Tags: angularjs

I have done this using $http.post as below:

```
$http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'www.someurl'+myid
          }).then(function successCallback(response) {
            console.log(response)
            }, function errorCallback(response) {
              console.log(response)
      });
```

Requirement is to make the same post call using $resource. I tried as below:

filter:

```
saffModuleServices.factory('Projects', ['$http', '$resource', '$appConstants',
  function ($http, $resource, $appConstants) {
    $http.defaults.useXDomain = true;
    delete $http.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
    var createDraftEndPoint=www.someurl/:id;
    var saveEmailDraftEndPoint=www.someurl.com
return {
     saveEmailDraft: function(){
     return $resource(saveEmailDraftEndPoint, {}, {
      update: {method: 'PUT', params: {},headers: {'Content-Type':'application/json'}}
    });
  },
     createDraft: function(){
        return $resource(createDraftEndPoint, {}, {
          post: {method: 'POST',param{id:''}}
        });
      },

}
}]);
```

controller:

```
saffModuleControllers.controller('ctrl', ['$scope', 'SaffNotification','Projects','$filter',
  function ($scope, Notification,Projects,$filter) {

    Projects.createDraft().post({id:myid}, function(response){

      Notification.success({message: $filter('translate')('administration_item_save_notification'), templateUrl: 'common/templates/toastr_success_template.html'});
      }, function(response){
        Notification.error({message: response.data.errorMessage, templateUrl: 'common/templates/toastr_error_template.html'});
      });

  }]);
```

error:
myId is going as data for this request, but I want to send that as param and no data should be sent. I could do that using $http.post
Can anyone suggest me how to make this request in $resource.post without editing $httpProvider in config, because I dont want to make 'data' parameter nil for other POST request.

Comment: you need to add the param to the defualt $resource(createDraftEndPoint' + /:id', { id: "@id" },post: {method: 'POST',param{id: '@id'}}

Comment: Thank you @Erez .It worked :)