# Angular Resource PUT Operation with Payload

Tags: angularjs, rest, put, angular-resource, payload

I have the following factory to send query to server:

```
app.factory('Request', ['$resource',
    function ($resource) {
        var res = $resource("bin/server.fcgi/REST/" + ':resourceName/:ID', {}, {
                get : {
                    method : 'GET'
                },
                put : {
                    method : "PUT"
                }
            });
        return {
            get : function (arguments, b, c) {
                return res.get(arguments, b, c).$promise;
            },
            put : function(arguments,b,c){
                return res.put(arguments, b, c).$promise;
            }
        };
    }
]);
```

I call it like this:

```
Request[methodName](params).then(successFunction).catch (failFunction);
```

However, if i want to send a PUT query:

```
Request["put"](params).then(successFunction).catch (failFunction);
```

where

```
params = {
   resourceName : "ATable",
   ID : 222,
   AProperty : "changedValue"
}
```

I take then following request: (so an error)

```
http://myadres.com/REST/ATable/222?AProperty=changedValue
```

instead of

```
http://myadres.com/REST/ATable/222
```

with payload

```
{ AProperty:changedValue }
```

What is wrong with this?

Comment: take a look on that question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38308156/how-to-make-resource-post-call-without-sending-data?noredirect=1#comment64036803_38308156 i comment there and you should do the same- you dont need the "+"

Comment: what do you mean exactly? I tried some versions of your answer but none of them worked. If you can give an answer, then we can discuss it on your answer.

Comment: show what you did try

Comment: `var res = $resource("bin/server.fcgi/REST/" + ':resourceName/:ID', {ID: 'ID'}, {
    put : {
     method : "PUT",
     params: {
      ID: "ID"
     }
    }
   });`

Answer (score 1):

```
app.service('Request', ['$resource',function ($resource) {
        var res = $resource('bin/server.fcgi/REST/:resourceName/:ID', 
            {resourceName: "@resourceName", ID: "@ID"}, 
            {
                get : { method : 'GET'},
                put : { method : "PUT", params: {resourceName:"@resourceName", ID: "@ID"}//you can leave the string empty if you dont want it to be a defualt value like ID:""
            });

        this.get = function () {
            return res.get().$promise;
        }
        this.put = function(obj){
            return res.put(obj).$promise; // it can be also {like json with your params}
        }
]);
```

and then call it from controller by

```
var obj = {
    ID:222,
    resourceName:'ATable'
}
Request.put(obj).then(function(data){
    //check whats the data
})
```

this is how it should be done 
maybe not the best way but should work

Comment: Now i take the following: `http://localhost/agenda/bin/server.fcgi/REST/:@resourceName/26` its very strange

Comment: the names have to be equals and if its empty it can be

Comment: the name `resourceName` is equal everywhere?

Comment: yes it should be but as you can see it works you just miss something

Comment: yeah the query is working now with the following: `$resource("bin/server.fcgi/REST/" + ':resourceName/:ID', {resourceName:"@resourceName", ID: '@ID'}, {
    put : {
     method : "PUT",
     params: {
      ID: '@ID',
      resourceName:"@resourceName"
     }
    }
   });` However `resourceName` is also contained in payload and it shouldn't go to server. So take now this error from server : `Unknown property: "resourceName"` how can we avoid that resourceName is not sent to server as a property ??

Comment: make it am empty by defualt like params: {resourceName: "" , ID: "@ID"}, but it can be default, it look like the id the resource name id

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117087/discussion-between-erez-and-asqan).